Server-side pagination. How to reset pagination to page 1 on sort?
I'm using ag-grid-vue enterprise 32.1.0.
Server-side pagination with server-side sort.
When i sort a column, the params passed to getRows() preserve the startRow and endRow of the current page. How can I reset the pagination to page 1 on sort? Staying on the current page makes no sense.
Thank you!

You can reset your pagination to page 1 by setting the paginationGoToPage prop to 0. This will change your pagination to page 1, regardless of your current page, in response to the sort change event.

const onFirstDataRendered = (params) => {
params.api.paginationGoToPage(0);
};

This answer is referenced from the Official AG Grid Documentation.

Am i correct in understanding that this will essentially double query? The way understand your suggestion:
Sort changes -> getRows() is called with wrong offset -> data queried -> then i do paginationGoToPage(0) and this will call getRows() again?

Nevermind, it does not double query! Thank you!
